# DataView.Dispose и подписанные события

Tags: c#, события

Есть код

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataView view = new DataView(table);
view.ListChanged += delegate {
  Console.WriteLine(1);
};
table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
view.Dispose();
table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
Console.ReadKey();
```

В консоль выводится поочередно две единицы, теперь вопрос: разве `Dispose` не разрывает связь с событиями? Если нет, то как разорвать связи при `Dispose`.

UPD: Внесу ясность, почему я сделал это пример через делегат, во время Dispose я не в курсе на какие события я подписан. Хотелось бы их все грохнуть.

Comment: `view.Dispose(); view = null;` - так

Comment: @Dmitry Неа! скопируйте себе код и проверьте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

работа с анонимными делегатами

```
var viewDelegate = delegate()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
};

// Подписаться
view.ListChanged += viewDelegate;

// Отписаться
view.ListChanged -= viewDelegate;
```

убийство объекта

```
view.Dispose(); 
view = null;
```

**UPD:** отписываемся от всего

```
var p = view.GetType().GetProperty("Events",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var list = (EventHandlerList)p.GetValue(view, null);
list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
```

Comment: Сори. Обновил вопрос, не зная подписок возможно ли от них отписаться?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Смотря откуда. Источник событий может выбросить все подписки, да. А вот вы, если не имеете подписки, не можете и отписаться. Это же логично: если вы не можете доказать, что подписка ваша, почему у вас должно быть право эту подписку отменить?

Comment: @Dmitry: Через рефлексию не айс: ненадёжно, не работает в partial trust и вообще обход явного запрета.

Comment: @VladD был бы вопрос :) а ответ найдется :) ну надо ТС убить все, пожалуйста, в ответе убийство всего :) когда поймет что надо бы знать на что подписался и на что надо отписаться тогда и вопросы будет ставить в правильном ключе

Comment: Походу мой тупняк, после Dispose в консоль ничего уже не пишется, а вторая единица возникает при Dispose. Видимо Dispose грохает связи с делегатами событий. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если класс ваш, то отписать всех можно легко:

```
ListChanged = null;
```

Проверка:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new Sender();
        new Client(s);
        s.Fire();
        s.UnsubscribeAll();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        s.Fire();
    }
}

class Client
{
    public Client (Sender s) { s.Test += OnTest; }
    void OnTest(object sender, EventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine("Client notified"); }
    ~Client() { Console.WriteLine("Client finalized"); }
}

class Sender
{
    public event EventHandler Test;
    public void Fire()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sender sends notification");
        if (Test != null) Test(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    public void UnsubscribeAll() { Test = null; }
}
```

выводит

> Sender sends notification
>   Client notified
>   Client finalized
>   Sender sends notification

Другое дело, что так делать не стоит: пускай клиенты отписываются сами. Или, возможно, вам нужен weak event manager?

Comment: К сожалению не мой. System.Data.DataView, Вопрос решён. Dispose всё же грохает связи с событиями.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Это его добрая воля, он по идее вовсе не обязан так делать.